# How to get HttpServletRequest in a Ring handler?

Tags: web-services, clojure, compojure, ring, noir

Is there a way to get the HttpServletRequest object in a Ring handler?
I am using Noir to develope a web app. I need to get the HttpServletRequest obj when handling a URI. So I use the (noir.request.ring-request) function to get back the ring request map which contains :servlet-request key, but the value is nil. Is this the right way to do it or do I miss something?

following is the code:

```
(ns my-app
     (:use noir.request))
(defpage [:get "/app"] []
     (str (ring-request)))
```

the result:

```
{:remote-addr "127.0.0.1", :scheme :http, :query-params {}, :session {}, :form-params {}, :multipart-params {}, :servlet #, :request-method :get, :query-string nil, :content-type nil, :cookies {"ring-session" {:value "eb509a65-d33a-40d2-9646-e2ff785428b0"}}, :uri "/app", :server-name "127.0.0.1", :params {}, :headers {"cookie" "ring-session=eb509a65-d33a-40d2-9646-e2ff785428b0", "accept-charset" "GBK,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3", "accept-language" "en-US,en;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.6,zh;q=0.4", "accept-encoding" "gzip,deflate,sdch", "accept" "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "user-agent" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.106 Safari/535.2", "connection" "keep-alive", "host" "127.0.0.1:8080"}, :servlet-request #, :content-length nil, :server-port 8080, :character-encoding nil, :servlet-response #, :body #, :servlet-context #}
```

Comment: Out of interest, what are you trying to do to the request object? Maybe there is some other way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the ring request map is constructed based on the adapter you are using for the webserver.  In the case of jetty, this happens in ring.adapter.jetty:

https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/blob/master/ring-jetty-adapter/src/ring/adapter/jetty.clj

If I were you, I would create my own adapter that explicitly adds what you need to the request map.  Specifically you would replace

```
request-map (servlet/build-request-map request)
```

with something like:

```
request-map (assoc (servlet/build-request-map request) :jetty-request request)
```